# How can I capture when time changes in a TimePicker if the "Soft" Keyboard is being used?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, timepicker, android-timepicker

Continuing with the question referred in the following link:

[How can I capture when time changes in a TimePicker if the keyboard is being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380761/how-can-i-capture-when-time-changes-in-a-timepicker-if-the-keyboard-is-being-used/)

I could solve the problem but it only works when you use the actual keyboard.  If you use the soft keyboard I can't get it to work.

I am programming in 1.6 version of the framework.

Any help will be much appreciated.

PS: The fact that I've search everywhere for the answer and have not been able to find it tells me that this must be so very simple or very much complicated.   Help?!

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the comment from Cody, you need to remove focus from the TimePicker when the dialog is closed.

You can use this, where tp is the TimePicker instance:

```
   public void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
   tp.clearFocus();
```

Comment: <rant>Unrelated, but does anyone else hate the way code is formatted in these answers?  The rendered output usually looks nothing like it does in the edit box... </rant>

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. If I use TimePickerDialog there's no problem.
For using TimePicker in a DialogPreference, this is the WORST workaround I've ever made, going down the view hierarchy of the TimePicker:

```
ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) timePicker.getChildAt(0);
ViewGroup numberPicker1 = (ViewGroup) v.getChildAt(0);
ViewGroup numberPicker2 = (ViewGroup) v.getChildAt(1);

String hours = ((EditText) numberPicker1.getChildAt(1)).getText().toString();
String mins = ((EditText) numberPicker2.getChildAt(1)).getText().toString();

String selectedTime = hours+":"+mins;
```

This way I could access the text directly which was typed in - but there SHOULD be a better way to manage keyboard inputs...

Comment: Cody... may be is the device.  I checked with the G1 and it was working fine, but it worked in a different way in my Samsung Moment.  Have you checked if the behavior is the same in other devices?

Comment: No, I didn't, I only know that my timepicker didn't behave as expected on an emulator. Perhaps you are right. Anyway, if it's not working properly on all target devices, there has to be a solution. You can't simply attach an OnTimeSetListener to a TimePicker, like for TimePickerDialog. It seems the OnTimeChangedListener only takes care of a manual input, if the respective EditText looses focus before the OK button is clicked. If it still has focus when clicking OK, the OnTimeChangedListener doesn't notice it.

Comment: @cody - Just came across this thread after running into this problem.  I have implemented your workaround and it seems to be functioning perfectly, but since this thread is so old, have you come across a better way to get the times from the TimePicker when using the soft keyboard?

Comment: yes, just clear the focus by calling "timePicker.clearFocus();" - that should do it ;) you can call it from onDialogClosed() (as seen in the post below)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:
I found out that this issue is only an issue depending on the device your working with.
I have a Samsung Moment, so after testing in other devices (obviously not all of them) and emulators I found out it was only happening with my phone.

The following link helped me solve my problem.  I hope it helps you...

http://blog.xiaad.com/2010/03/android-datepicker-years-before-2000.html

N-Joy!

Simmone